# How do you make a node js async await wait until process is finished before moving to the next line of code?

Tags: node.js, async-await

I know this question has been asked but the answers are not fitting my situation

The below code is not waiting on wait before going to next line of code.  What am I doing wrong?

`getStatistics` should wait until process is finished before executing `getTileGeoJsonBB`

```
await getStatistics();  
let bb = getTileGeoJsonBB(tileInfo);
```

Async function:

```
async function getStatistics() {
        tileStats = await converter.calculateStatistics(tilePath);
}
```

The above code `converter.calculateStatistics` calls this async function

```
module.exports.calculateStatistics = async function (inputFilePath) {
    const pipeline = promisify(stream.pipeline);
    let png = new PNG({})
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        fs.createReadStream(inputFilePath)
            .pipe(png)
            .on("parsed", () => {
                // do parsing logic
                resolve(getTileStatistics(png))
            })
    })
}

let getTileStatistics = function (png) {
    stats = {};
    stats.minHeight = Number.MAX_VALUE;
    stats.maxHeight = Number.MIN_VALUE;
return stats
```

[image]

Comment: You're not doing anything with `pipeline` which is suspicious to me. Other than that, if you want your code to wait until right after the `parsed` event triggers, then I think you are doing everything right.

Comment: Maybe try adding `.on("error", (err) => reject(err))` to see if it gets invoked

Comment: Evert, I removed the pipeline code, it was left over from another attempt at getting this working.  Christian, added error code no errors logged.

Comment: ok I think it is working now but I am not sure I understand why.  I changed this let getTileStatistics = function to async function getTileStatistics()  basically just adding async to the getTileStatistics function.  However I could not add an await when calling the function ie resolve(await getTileStatistics(png)) but it now seems to work.  Any ideas why?

Comment: I take that back I was in debug mode testing and it worked but running real-time it still does not wait correctly.  Any ideas?

Comment: Never mind it is working I was calling the wrong function.  TY